# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with tail recursion

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Why i'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when i call the first function with a big number like 2000 and i'm getting no error from the second implementation?

Will not both reserve the same amount of memory?

```
object TailRecursion extends App{

  @tailrec
  def repeatString (str: String, n:Integer ): String = {
    if (n == 0) ""
    else if (n == 1) str
    else repeatString(str+str, n-1)
  }

  @tailrec
  def repeatString(str:String, n:Integer, accumulator:String):String ={
    if(n==0) accumulator
    else repeatString(str, n-1, str+accumulator)
  }

  println(repeatString("teste", 0))
  println(repeatString("teste", 1))
  println(repeatString("teste", 2))
  println(repeatString("teste", 2000))
}
```

Comment: For building large strings, use **StringBuilder** _(and append, instead of prepend)_. - BTW, the two functions are not equivalent.

Comment: Also JVM doesn't have tail call optimization. Clojure built a lot of guards around this but I am not super confident what is available in Scala. Bottom line You have to be really careful what you do in a tail rec call in any jvm based language

Comment: @sinanspd is not `@tailrec` preventing the code from compiling if the snipped does not translate to an tail recursive implementation?

Comment: Yeah the first is not the same as the second, you are concatenating string ^1999 in the first, that is why you are getting out of memory. In the second you are concatenating str*2000

Comment: Try `println(repeatString("teste",5))` and compare results. `repeatString()` #1 is building a **much** bigger result string.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, totally my bad, my logic was broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Both will not reserve the same amount of memory.

Let's try to do the one with `OutOfMemory` error with the for expression in Scala. It will roughly translate to below code:

```
def repeatStringLoop(string: String, n: Integer): String = {
  var resultString = string
  if (n == 0) ""
  else if (n == 1) string
  else {
    for (i <- 0 until n) {
      resultString = resultString.concat(resultString)
    }    
    resultString
  }
}
```

If you run the code, it will throw the same error. It's because you are trying to concatenate each modified string twice - causing to take more memory - which is not same as concatenate string "teste" to the result string.

However, it's better to use `StringBuilder` for this kind of string concatenation.